# Ionic 3 - Read NFC Card?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, nfc

I’m stuck for weeks trying read NFC card from my ionic project.

Running the app on a real device (Samsung S7 Edge with Android).

I’m following this:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/nfc/

Then, I installed the plugin on my project:

```
ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-nfc

npm install @ionic-native/nfc
```

Only need read the Card Tag Id into the variable **tagId (string)** to show it.

My source:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { NFC, Ndef } from '@ionic-native/nfc/ngx';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    NFC,
    Ndef,
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Platform, AlertController, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NFC, Ndef } from '@ionic-native/nfc/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  tagId: string;

  constructor(public platform: Platform,
              private alertCtrl: AlertController, 
              private toastCtrl: ToastController,
              public navCtrl: NavController, 
              private nfc: NFC,
              private ndef: Ndef) {

    this.platform.ready().then(() => { 
      this.addListenNFC();
    });

  } // del constructor

    addListenNFC() {
      console.log('entra a addListenNFC');

      this.nfc.addNdefListener(() => {
        console.log('successfully attached ndef listener');
      }, (err) => {
        console.log('error attaching ndef listener', err);

        let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: err,
          duration: 1000,
          position: 'bottom'
        });

        toast.present(); 

      }).subscribe((event) => {
        console.log('received ndef message. the tag contains: ', event.tag);
        console.log('decoded tag id', this.nfc.bytesToHexString(event.tag.id));

        let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: this.nfc.bytesToHexString(event.tag.id),
          duration: 1000,
          position: 'bottom'
        });

        toast.present(); 
      });

    }
}
```

**home.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      NFC-Access Card
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h1>Please Scan Access Card</h1>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-content>
      <p>Account Tag ID: {{ tagId  }}</p>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

I’m getting this error in the console:

[console error adding listener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8fKc.jpg)

Why do I get this error when adding the listener?
What is wrong??

Thanks.

Comment: so are you running this code on Android device? or in the browser?

Comment: Running the app on a real device (Samsung S7 Edge with Android).

Comment: Was there a solution to your problem @DiegoRoque? I have just about the same code as yours, but it's not working. I'm not getting any errors either. I hope you have better luck than I do. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Its a version incompatibility error. Check your `ionic.config.json`. If your type is ionic angular then you need to downgrade your nfc plugin version to 4.x.x. Therefore when you are importing the plugin to your `app.module.ts` and your respective components file(s), it becomes;

```
import { NFC, NDef } from '@ionic-native/nfc'
```

instead of:

```
import { NFC, NDef } from '@ionic-native/nfc/ngx'
```